# MOSS max upload size differs from Central Admin

Tags: file-upload

Central Admin shows our max upload size to be 90 megs, but trials of even text files at 35 megabtyes won't upload. Smaller files are fine.

Where should we look now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of things. The following article outlines most of the usual causes: [Configuring Large File Support](http://blog.gavin-adams.com/2007/06/28/configuring-large-file-support/)

Comment: I have seen that information. Doesn't apply to us. The failure occurs within a few seconds.
   One factor of unknown relevance is that we recently switched to a Sql Server cluster.

Comment: Although we have not been timing out, the answer proved to be our change to IIS7, which has a default(?) max upload size much lower than we needed (at least 35 megs). This is done in the Web.Config files.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of error are you receiving?  Not sure where in CA you're looking but you'll want to check the application management section of your particular web app.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you need to change the size in MOSS as well as in IIS.

Have a look at [this article](http://prasanjitmandal.blogspot.com/2010/07/increase-sharepoint-upload-limit.html).